# Notice when using an object

Tags: php, pdo, phpexcel

I have this simple request :

```
if($donnees->pays == 1)
 {
    $sql = "SELECT code_postal, nom as nom_ville FROM localite_be WHERE id = ".$donnees->code_postal_off;
 }
 elseif($donnees->pays == 2)
 {
    $sql = "SELECT code_postal, nom as nom_ville FROM localite_fr WHERE id = ".$donnees->code_postal_off;

 }
 else
 {
    $sql = "SELECT code_postal, nom as nom_ville FROM localite_lux WHERE id = ".$donnees->code_postal_off;
 }
 $cp_ville = $bdd->prepare($sql);
 $cp_ville->execute();

 $res_cp_ville = $cp_ville->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

I obtain an object :

> stdClass Object
>   (
>       [code_postal] => 7060
>       [nom_ville] => SOIGNIES
>   )

stdClass Object
(
    [code_postal] => 7134
    [nom_ville] => RESSAIX
)

and this notice :

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/web998/public_html/classes/Excel/Classes/impression_xlsx_demandes_agrements.php on line 561

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/web998/public_html/classes/Excel/Classes/impression_xlsx_demandes_agrements.php on line 562

Lines 561 and 562 are the followings :

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('G'.$i, $res_cp_ville->code_postal);
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('H'.$i, $res_cp_ville->nom_ville); 


 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($res_cp_ville);
 echo "</pre>";
```

This is the whole code :

```
    //je crée une nouvelle sheet Excel
    $objPHPExcel->createSheet();
    //je la mets en active
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1)->setTitle('Demandes de renouvellements');

    //Demandes de renouvellements
    $sql = "SELECT pharmacien.*,
                   officine.ref_type_officine,
                   officine.telephone,
                   officine.mail,
                   officine.province,
                   officine.adresse as addr_off,
                   pays.libelle,
                   province_be.nom as prov,
                   officine.ref_code_postal as code_postal_off
            FROM pharmacien
            LEFT JOIN agrement
            ON pharmacien.ref_agrement = agrement.id
            LEFT JOIN officine
            ON pharmacien.ref_identification = officine.ref_identification
            LEFT JOIN pays
            ON pharmacien.pays = pays.id
            LEFT JOIN province_be
            ON officine.province = province_be.ID
            WHERE ( date_soumission IS NOT NULL AND ref_type_agrement = '2'  )
            ";


   //echo $sql;
   $pharmaciens = $bdd->prepare($sql);
   $pharmaciens->execute();

   $res = $pharmaciens->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

   $i = 2;
   $temp_nombre_jours = 0;
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', 'NOM');
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B1', 'PRENOM');
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C1', 'TYPE OFFICINE');
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D1', 'PAYS');
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E1', 'PROVINCE');
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F1', 'ADRESSE OFFICINE');
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('G1', 'CP OFFICINE');
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('H1', 'VILLE OFFICINE');
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('I1', 'TELEPHONE');
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('J1', 'MAIL');

   foreach($res as $donnees)
   {
     $styleArray = array('font' => array('bold' => true));

     //je mets en gras le contenu de ces cellules
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('D1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('F1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('G1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('H1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('I1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('J1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('K1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$i, $donnees->nom);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$i, $donnees->prenom);


    if($donnees->ref_type_officine == 1)
    {
        $objPHPExcel -> getActiveSheet() -> setCellValue('C'.$i, 'Officine ouverte au public');    
    }
    else
    {
        $objPHPExcel -> getActiveSheet() -> setCellValue('C'.$i, 'Officine hospitaliere');    
    }

    //pays
    if($donnees->pays == 1)
    {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D'.$i, "BELGIQUE");    
    }
    elseif($donnees->pays == 2)
    {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D'.$i, "FRANCE");    
    }
    else
    {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D'.$i, "LUXEMBOURG");    
    }

     //province
     $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$i, $donnees->prov);


     $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F'.$i, $donnees->addr_off);

     if($donnees->pays == 1)
     {
        $sql = "SELECT code_postal, nom as nom_ville FROM localite_be WHERE id = ".$donnees->code_postal_off;
     }
     elseif($donnees->pays == 2)
     {
        $sql = "SELECT code_postal, nom as nom_ville FROM localite_fr WHERE id = ".$donnees->code_postal_off;

     }
     else
     {
        $sql = "SELECT code_postal, nom as nom_ville FROM localite_lux WHERE id = ".$donnees->code_postal_off;
     }
     $cp_ville = $bdd->prepare($sql);
     $cp_ville->execute();

     $res_cp_ville = $cp_ville->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

     $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('G'.$i, $res_cp_ville->code_postal);
     $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('H'.$i, $res_cp_ville->nom_ville);   



     $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('I'.$i, $donnees->telephone);
     $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('J'.$i, $donnees->mail);


     $i = $i+1;
   }//fin du foreach

   //redimensionnement des colonnes afin d'avoir des colonnes en autosize
   for($col = 'A'; $col !== 'L'; $col++)
   {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
        ->getColumnDimension($col)
        ->setAutoSize(true);
    }
```

Comment: The code should work. The error may be due to something else: Write the code in two different lines like this:
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet() {new line here}
                        ->SetCellValue('G'.$i, $res_cp_ville->code_postal);

Answer (score 0):

I thing you are trying to export data to excel.
Have you created object `$objPHPExcel = new Excel();`  with your excel class.

Comment: I created it, yes.  I add my whole code, see above please.  Thank you